# how to run libmodbus

Tags: ros, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I added

```
include_directories(include /usr/include/libmodbus)
```

to the CMakeList.txt of my package, and my test node is

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <libmodbus/src/modbus.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  modbus_t *Scara;
  Scara = modbus_new_tcp("192.168.1.219", 502);
        if (modbus_connect(Scara) == -1) {
            ROS_ERROR("Conexion fallida");
            modbus_free(Scara);
        }else{
            ROS_INFO("Conexion exitosa");
        }                      
        
  return 0;
}
```

but when i run catkin_make i get the following errors

```
In function `main':
scaraListen.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `modbus_new_tcp'
scaraListen.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `modbus_connect'
scaraListen.cpp:(.text+0x135): undefined reference to `modbus_free' 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that it's not linking to the library, but when i add

```
target_link_libraries(main /usr/include/libmodbus.so)
```

to the `CMakeList.txt` and try to compile i get:

```
(target_link_libraries):
   Cannot specify link libraries for target "main" which is not built by this project.
```

Where i'm messing up?

EDIT: my complete `CMakeList.txt` looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pointCloud)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pcl_conversions
  pcl_msgs
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  tf
  laser_geometry
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(include /usr/include/libmodbus)

add_executable(converter src/converter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(converter ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(converter pointCloud_conv)

add_executable(tfTest src/tftest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tfTest ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(tfTest pointCloud_conv)

add_executable(scaraListen src/scaraListen.cpp)
target_link_libraries(scaraListen ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(scaraListen pointCloud_conv)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231243/how-to-run-libmodbus/) by [Christian Hidalgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24061/christian-hidalgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-07**:
This seems like a simple linking problem. Can you please *add* your `CMakeLists.txt` to your post? Use the *edit* button/link for that. Please do not include all the boilerplate comments, just the commands.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-07**:
Also: in general it's not a good idea to hard code paths to libraries and headers / include paths. CMake supports some nice features for auto-detection of locations of such things, and I think you're not using them.

**Comment by [sonyccd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25477/sonyccd/) on 2016-04-07**:
I had some problems with libmodbus so I just wrote a ros driver to prevent others from having to figure it out.  Let me know if this helps. Feel free to build on this for your own project.

https://github.com/sonyccd/ros_plc_modbus

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-07**:
@sonyccd: I appreciate your contribution and the package, but this it is not an answer, so please don't post it as one. This is what comments are for.

**Comment by [sonyccd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25477/sonyccd/) on 2016-04-07**:
Good to know thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> It seems that it's not linking to the library, but when i add

> ```
> target_link_libraries(main /usr/include/libmodbus.so)
> ```

> to the CMakeList.txt and try to compile i get:

> ```
> (target_link_libraries):
> ```

```
   Cannot specify link libraries for target "main" which is not built by this project.
```

And that is because `main` is not a *target* that you define in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

You can only link libraries against things for which you have a `add_executable(..)` or a `add_library(..)` statement. In your case, that would be `converter`, `tfTest` and `scaraListen`.

From the error message you posted, it would appear that the `main` function you posted is in a file called `scaraListen.cpp`, so I'm guessing you should add the `libmodbus.so` library to the `target_link_libraries(scaraListen ..)` statement (which is similar to what @sonyccd posted).

PS: as I wrote in my comment, you might want to avoid hard-coding absolute paths to headers and libraries in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All I did to compile was add this to the cmake.

```
target_link_libraries(ros_plc_modbus
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   modbus
 )
```

and added this to the cpp file

```
#include <modbus/modbus.h>
```

---

Originally posted by [sonyccd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25477/sonyccd/) with karma: 58 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3